# Testing file upload with an existing test file (phpunit)

Tags: laravel, file, testing, file-upload, phpunit

im testing a laravel route that receives an excel file, reads and analize its content. Since i can't fake this file (it has to contain actual information for the route to work) ive decided to store a test file and send it to the endpoint, this is what i have so far:

```
public function UploadFile() {
        $file = new UploadedFile (
            'pathtofile.xlsx',
            'test_file.xlsx',
            null, null, false);
        $response = $this->post(
            '/api/uploadfile',
            [ 'file' => $file ],
        );
        $response->assertOk();
    }
```

In the controller i do several things, the part that is failing is this:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
    {   
        $fileNew = $request->file('file');
        dd(is_uploaded_file($fileNew->getPathname())); // this returns false
        $copyFile = move_uploaded_file($fileNew->getPathname(), $nameFileWithRoute);
        dd($copyFile) //this returns false too
```

I have also tried using File like this:

```
public function UploadFile() {
        $file = new File('pathtofile.xlsx');
        $response = $this->post(
            '/api/uploadfile',
            [ 'file' => $file ],
        );
        $response->assertOk();
    }
```

This method works even less, since `$fileNew = $request->file('file');` returns null

I want a method that allows me to test file upload with an existing test file, rather than faking it with the usual methods

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your file path isn't where you think it is.

We did this recently and considered the file as part of the test fixtures, and implemented a helper method like so:

```php
private function createTestFile(): string
{
    $fileName = 'test_csv.csv';
    $path = storage_path() . '/testdata.csv';

    is_dir($path) && mkdir($path);

    $data = [['id', 'name', 'age'], [123, 'bob', 42]];
    $resource = fopen($path . '/' . $fileName, 'w');
    foreach($data as $row){
        fputcsv($resource, $row);
    }
    fclose($resource);

    return $path . '/' . $fileName;
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function testFileUpload(): void
{
    $testFilePath = $this->createTestFile();

    $request = [
        'file' => new UploadedFile($testFilePath, 'testFile.csv')
    ];

    $response = $this->post('/api/fileUploadTest', $request);
}
```

Then over in our controller just access as we usually would

```php
class FileUploadController extends Controller
{
    public function uploadTest(Request $request): Response
    {
        $files = $request->file('file');
        dd($files->getContent());
        // """ // app\Http\Controllers\FileUploadController.php:13
        // id,name,age\n
        // 123,bob,42\n
        // """

        return response('foobar');
    }
}
```

Make sure to `.gitignore` any local test storage directories. Possibly consider removing any test data as part of the test teardowns also.

nb: if you absolutely must use an .xlsx file, just add it to `storage/testdata/file.xlsx` and access with `storage_path() ' ./testdata/file.xlsx` and commit it to VCS.

Comment: Thank you for your time, your answer is perfectly valid, but in my case it does'nt work, in the controller the move_uploaded_file method is used, wich when used with the UploadedFile returns false, wich means php doesnt recognize it as a valid uploaded file, could there be a way around this?

Comment: please note that when i dd $request->file('file') it shows something, so it does recognize the file, the problems seems to be with php itself. This works in development by the way, so i dont really see how to get the test to run